# JSON cannot get data into SQLite3 table

Tags: json, swift, macos

I have seen quite a few posts on this question and none seem to answer my question.  They are usually far more complicated than what I am asking.  I have a list of one or more stocks that I would like to get the latest price for from the Internet.  I found a nice API for doing that and was excited to create a simple structure and do the basics of a URLSession. I was able to pull the data into my structured format and print it in the console no problem.  For example:

```
Quote(symbol: "C", companyName: "Citigroup Inc.", latestPrice: 68.86)
```

I want to update my SQLite3 database records with the current price.  I cannot get the data out.

So I have my opentrades array based on a model:

```
class OpenTradeDur: NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var trNo: Int
    @objc dynamic var trPDate: String
    @objc dynamic var trTicker: String
    @objc dynamic var trDur: String
    @objc dynamic var trCurPrice: Double
```

and the Quote structure is simple:

```
struct Quote: Decodable {
    let symbol: String
    let companyName: String
    let latestPrice: Double
}
```

I have tried multiple variations of functions and actions and variables but my latest attempt that is still no closer to working is running in my viewDidLoad of my ViewController where I do some initial setup:

```
for _ in opentrades {
    rn = rn + 1
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/\(opentrades[rn].trTicker)/quote")
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in
    guard let data = data else { return }
    do {
        let quote = try JSONDecoder.decode(Quote.self,from: data)
        print(quote)
        self.opentrades[rn].trCurPrice = quote.latestPrice
        } catch {}
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

I found a few posts that talk about completion handlers but even in those examples only give an answer that ends up printing to console.  I just need a simple implementation. What I really need is a function that I can just call and say:

```
price = getPrice(stockTicker)
```

eg. `price = getPrice("C")`

and what that is doing behind the scenes if getting the JSON data from

```
https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/C/quote
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

[2018-10-25]

I have managed to get this working in a fashion by creating a delegate protocol in the class I have performing the URLSession and then extending my ViewController with the delegate.  And this works for a single quote at a time.  I can initiate the process with a button and when the data comes back through the delegate's didLoad function I have it update the screen.  But I was looking for a backend process to make multiple calls to the quote api and update multiple records.  But I could not get that to synch up.  But I had a thought and went back to the API documentation found a batch call where I can return all of the data for multiple stocks in one call.  That is exactly what I need however I am stuck once again.  The returned data is JSON data but not jsonapi.org compliant.  I am going to post this as a new question and try hard to make sense in my asking of the question.

Edit:  I received a great response from my new question and it has solved the problem I was experiencing here so I will provide an update.

As I tried to explain previously, my application runs through a list of open stock trades at startup and wants to update the latest price for each of them.  I have an array I run through to set the price and then update my database to save those changes.  Then my app opens with the new data in place.

I now have a function that takes a stock symbol as an input and returns the price immediately...

```
func getPrice(ticker: String) -> Double {
    var price = 0.0
    let urlString = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/\(ticker)/quote"
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string: urlString)!)
    do {
        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Quote.self,from: data)
        price = response.latestPrice
    } catch let jsonErr { print("Error decoding JSON:",jsonErr)}
    return price
}
```

I simply run through my array of trades and set the price...

```
opentrades[rn].trCurPrice = getPrice(ticker: opentrades[rn].trTicker)
```

I will be testing this to see how it works out without using a URLSession especially during the trading day and times of high activity and potential network latency.

Comment: There's nothing in this question related to SQLite. It's really unclear what you are asking or where your issue is.

Comment: Thanks Maddy.  This issue is, I can get the data from a remote server, I can print it out ...the print(quote) line.. .and the very next line I try to set the value from quote.latestPrice into opentrades[rn].trCurPrice and nothing happens.  There is no error.  It just does not work. It is maddening.